# Why doesn't Datomic have an EATV index?

Tags: algorithm, indexing, datomic

I would think that a common operation on any DBMS, even Datomic, would be to retrieve the most recent values of attribute(s) of a given entity.  E.g. show me Joe's (most recent) address.

Given the [4 available indices](http://docs.datomic.com/indexes.html) all have T at the end, it seems like this common operation would not be very efficient.  For example, using EAVT, you would have to search through all of the values for a given entity-attribute pair, in order to find the one with the most recent T.

Is there something missing or wrong from this analysis?  If not, doesn't that imply that there should be an EATV index?

Answer (score 3):

Datomic's indexes are covering indexes - see the [docs on this topic](http://docs.datomic.com/indexes.html#basics). You're not navigating multiple trees of pointers to flesh out an entity, you're actually retrieving the (sorted) datoms about an entity by navigating the index tree for EAVT (by E) and retrieving those datoms. In fact, entities themselves are just inferred from the datoms about them, they're not otherwise implemented.

To navigate EAVT, You navigate to the datoms about an E through the index tree and retrieve the leaf segment, with contains sorted E,A,V,Tx datoms about the entity for the current database (as of its basis-T). Remember also that Datomic supports cardinality many attributes.

Answer (score 0):

It will be rare to have few entities, with few attributes and massive amounts of churn on the values. That would need to be the case for a EATV index to help.

Its the EA portion of the index that really matters for lookup speed. Taking the most recent value of all the attributes for a given entity is a rapid filter over a contiguous set of datoms an EAVT index (which like all indexes in datomic is a [covering index](http://docs.datomic.com/indexes.html) meaning the ordered datoms are actually present within the index structure).

Comment: What is the use case that makes EAVT preferable to EATV?

Comment: Fair question, to which I don't know the answer. If I had to guess it might be to do with internal implementation with T in a consistent place in all datom indexes. In isolation EATV would seem to make as much sense as EAVT.

Answer (score 0):

For finding the most recent value of an attribute you don't need to search the history db.

```
(d/q '[:find ?address
       :where [?e :name "Joe"]
              [?e :address ?address]]
  db)
```

will give you the most recent address of Joe (in the db version provided to the query) and efficiently uses EAVT.

There's some more background on the topic on the [Datomic google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/datomic/%243Adb%242FtxInstant%2420performance/datomic/dpCN-QGr1pA/lSqSrNwiDSAJ).

Comment: This only shows the querying syntax, it does not answer, what happens on the background. How do you know, whether the Datomic internally itterates over all past values of current E&A?

Answer (score 0):

For the retrieving of the most current value, Datomic doesn't have to iterate over all possible values: Datomic keeps the current values in a separate B-tree (called current part), so this should be really fast. For the further explanation, read this AWESOME blog:

http://tonsky.me/blog/unofficial-guide-to-datomic-internals/

However, why is EAVT preferred to EATV is unclear to me.

Also, it is unclear, how Datomic performs as-of queries. When as-of-ing Datomic has to join the history part and current part (terminology from the article mentioned above) which yields exactly to the problem you originally posed.