# What is the use case that makes EAVT index preferable to EATV?

Tags: indexing, datomic

From what I understand, EATV (which Datomic does not have) would be great fit for as-of queries. On the other hand, I see no use-case for EAVT.

Comment: if you ever find your way back here, I was originally confused by the same question. I figured it out though https://stackoverflow.com/a/57895511/58961

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't Datomic have an EATV index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22536024/why-doesnt-datomic-have-an-eatv-index)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not looking for a single value at a specific point in time. You are looking for a set of values up to a specific point in time T. History is on a per value basis (not attribute basis).

For example, assert X, retract X then assert X again. These are 3 distinct facts over 3 distinct transactions. You need to compute that X was added, then removed and then possibly added again at some point.

You can do this with SQL:

```
create table Datoms (
  E bigint not null,
  A bigint not null,
  V varbinary(1536) not null,
  T bigint not null,
  Op bit not null --assert/retract
)

select E, A, V
from Datoms
where E = 1 and T <= 42
group by E, A, V
having 0 < sum(case Op when 1 then +1 else -1 end)
```

The fifth component `Op` of the datom tells you whether the value is asserted (1) or retracted (0). By summing over this value (as +1/-1) we arrive at either 1 or 0.

> Asserting the same value twice does nothing, and you always retract the old value before you assert a new value. The last part is a prerequisite for the algorithm to work out this nicely.

With an EAVT index, this is a very efficient query and it's quite elegant. You can build a basic Datomic-like system in just 150 lines of SQL like this. It is the same pattern repeated for any permutation of EAVT index that you want.

Comment: Thank you for the nice SQL analogy! So what you are saying is that if I query 

give me attribute A of entity E at time T, 

the engine will do:
1) quick access of A.E
2) linear scan of all V's to see which one is the latest

This'll be done in :

O(lg(db_size) + X)

time, where X is the number of changes of attribute A on entity E that were ever done. Is this correct?

(I used lg(db_size) as an upper bound for accessing the B-tree indexes)

Comment: If and only if you go via the history database. Datomic specifically will have the latest value in it's **live** index. The **live** index only has the current assertions for some combination of E and A. So it's access time of the **live** index will be constant over time but the history database (which is just a different way to access the database will have to do a bit more computation).

Comment: Though, Datomic is built upon the assumption that changes to individual facts are a rare occurrence. You don't go back and update stuff in place all the time. If you do, then Datomic is the wrong tool for the job. It doesn't do write heavy workloads. It is a conscious decision from the authors not to.

Comment: @TomasKulich BTW, It's documented here https://docs.datomic.com/on-prem/filters.html#the-present-pays-no-penalty

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I didn't know about the live index. That makes a lot of sense - querying past doesn't need to be that fast.

Comment: One more thing: Getting value of an attribute at a time would be fast, if Datomic had EATV index - which AFAIK it doesn't. Do you know why is this so? It's OK to make an assumption that values don't change that often but still it'd be nice if the DB was fast even under such assumptions. This is boggling me from the very beginning especially since EATV looks as SO much better index than existing EAVT :)

Comment: The best idea I have for this is that it's a performance thing. as T goes forward in time you want writes to go to the end of the B-tree index. EAVT does a better job than EATV in that case. You also have all values of an attribute grouped together. It's EAV + T not EA + T + V :)

The SQL example I gave you is, basically the EAVT history index. I doesn't work if we switch T for V because of how we aggregate to create a live value in the SQL world.

But at this point I'm just guessing.

Comment: I don't believe that determining whether a datom is asserted or retracted is achieved by summing the operations but rather by simply looking at the most recent one and ignoring the rest.

Comment: @DavidBraun no, this is just the simplest SQL query I could think of at the time that computes the right thing. This comes in to play if you want to source as-of-t and since-t databases from history. The actual transducer you end up implementing is very elegant and yes if you have a sorted B-tree that you can traverse with iterators it is much more direct and efficient. It's just not something SQL does well.

Answer (score 3):

This is analogous to row/primary key access. From the [docs](http://docs.datomic.com/indexes.html): "The EAVT index provides efficient access to everything about a given entity. Conceptually this is very similar to row access style in a SQL database, except that entities can possess arbitrary attributes rather then being limited to a predefined set of columns."

The immutable time/history side of Datomic is a motivating use case for it, but in general, it's still optimized around typical database operations, e.g. looking up an entity's attributes and their values.

Update:

Datomic stores datoms (in segments) in the index tree. So you navigate to a particular E's segment using the tree and then retrieve the datoms about that E in the segment, which are EAVT datoms. From your comment, I believe you're thinking of this as the navigation of more b-tree like structures at each step, which is incorrect. Once you've navigated to the E, you are accessing a leaf segment of (sorted) datoms.

Comment: But I don't see how looking up entity's attribute's value can benefit from EAVT. I mean, the EA part is quite obvious, but why VT at the end? As I understand it, VT means, you have all (past) values of a given attribute in one B-TREE and ONLY WHEN picking one concrete value, you find out, at what time this value was set (and you don't even know, whether there exists newer value for this attribute!). Although, this blog post http://tonsky.me/blog/unofficial-guide-to-datomic-internals/ indicates, this probably won't be a big deal for most of the queries, it is a big deal for as-of queries!

Comment: I've updated the answer above. VT is not a b-tree, the index itself is a covering index which contains all the datoms. You only navigate the index tree to get the leaf segment which contains all datoms about the entity - you don't continue to get AVT, etc. by walking a tree.

Comment: That's an interesting fact, but I still don't see how it answers the originally posed question. To illustrate the problem: Say, I'm changing value of an attribute every second to some new, unique value. After some time, there's a huge amount of such datoms. Now if I ask Datomic for some attr value in some specific time, what can the engine do? From your post it seems it has to fetch all the datoms for a given entity (maybe they even don't fit into one segment?) and has to iterate over it since bin-search is not applicable here?

Comment: Ben thanks for your helpful response. Do the segment IDs correspond to their respective components, e.g. the EAVT index id would be E, while AEVT id would be the A?

Comment: @TomasKulich this is a false premise. Datomic doesn't want you to do that and it is built on an assumption that you do not modify the same value in absurdum. I think it's a very reasonable constraint. If you have data that changes (high write churn) Datomic is not the database for you but you could easily complement Datomic with SQL for those scenarios. I think it's important to understand that Datomic isn't an be-all, end-all database, even if it is very powerful.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have inside knowledge but after creating my own implementation, this is what makes sense to me:

EAVT allows for determining current or recent values inexpensively:  For a given E and A, seek your iterator to the first value (V).  You will find the most recent T and that's your current value, or you can go back in time to find recent values quickly.  After this, seek your index iterator forward to the next value and repeat.

EATV would take longer to do this.  For a given E and A, you could look at the most recent T but that wouldn't tell you about all values V—it would tell you only about values changed in that particular transaction.  You'd have to iterate through older values of T, perhaps indefinitely, to get to all values.